# How to make https REST request using make_rest_request function?

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to use apex_web_service.make_rest_request function to invoke POST method of REST serice.

So if I run something like this -

```
SELECT utl_http.request('https://aa.xxxxxxx.com:port/dev/api/v1/asd',NULL,'file:/u01/wallet','WalletPass') from dual;
```

I can get the HTML back. But, how I can use POST method with `apex_web_service.make_rest_request` sending body and using same wallet and basic AUTH. :)

I tried with code below, but it retirves - `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MAKE_REST_REQUEST'`

```
SELECT apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
              p_url              => 'https://aa.xxxxxxx.com:port/dev/api/v1/asd',
              p_http_method      => 'POST',
              p_username         => 'asdasd',
              p_password         => 'asdadsasd',
              p_wallet_path      => 'file:/u01/wallet', 
              p_wallet_password  => 'WalletPass',
              p_body => '') FROM DUAL;
```

I am on APEX 18.1

Comment: I googled "apex_web_service post example" and got many hits from very trustworthy sources. Did you go through those ? If so - what failed ?

Comment: I didn't find "apex_web_service post example" as https call with the walllet

Comment: @KoenLostrie I eddited the question

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation of APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/MAKE_REST_REQUEST-Function.html#GUID-C77BB45A-8968-470C-8243-BADB63743DE9

The `p_wallet_password` parameter is not right; it should be `p_wallet_pwd`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed that, and now, getting the ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1017
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380.

Comment: but, this one works - SELECT utl_http.request('https://aa.xxxxxxx.com:port/dev/api/v1/asd',NULL,'file:/u01/wallet','WalletPass') from dual;

Comment: The ORA-24247 indicates that outbound connections to the server you are calling are not allowed. The call happens through pl/sql so this needs to be configured in your database, this is pretty well documented and blogged about.

Comment: @KoenLostrie If that is the problem why it works with utl_http.request?

Comment: It is the problem with the make_rest_request function. You're comparing apples with pears. Does a GET call work with make_rest_request ? I only know that I have done this in previous projects and I'm trying to help you through the different errors by guiding you in the right direction - I can't answer this "why does x work and doesn't y".

Comment: It is the same with GET, sorry for the confusion. Could be that make_rest_request is using APEX schema user as default? If yes, should I grant ACL privs to APEX schema user, such as APEX_180200?

Comment: That was the problem, I assigned ACL privileges to APEX scheme user, and it works now. :)